# Lanch new Docker image when memory limit is reached

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Sorry if this is a dumb question but i'm quite new to Docker.

I understand that, if a the --memory parameter is set and the container uses all the memory, Docker will kill the container if the container.

I wonder if it's possible to create a new container (without killing the previous one) when the container reaches a certain memory limit defined by me.

Comment: Docker doesn't have a way to do this on its own.  It's also unclear how much it will help; most languages have a garbage collector and from Docker's point of view will use as much memory as they're given.  In a Kubernetes context you might look at a HorizontalPodAutoscaler as a way to automatically create more Pods.

Answer (score 0):

docker does not have built in service scaling.

most implementations ive seen for docker that do this use:

- prometheus, a monitoring server that can scrape docker container metrics.
- alertmanager, a server that, given metrics to monitor on a prometheus server, can raise alerts when thresholds are reached.
- a custom piece of code using the docker golang sdk that increases or decreases the number of service replicas in response to alert thresholds.